# Is there a valid rationale for blocking HTTP traffic to ports other than 80?

Tags: security, http, web, port

I installed TomCat using the default port: 8080.  The hosted application started to get some significant use.  Today I got an email from someone else who says that their network security rules do not allow them to access any web server that is not on port 80.

I resolved the issue by running TomCat on both port 80 and 8080, however, I keep thinking how silly this "security rule" is.  Clearly, harmful servers can be run on any port, including port 80.  Does running a server on port 80 make it in any way more trustable?  I am assuming that this rule was created at one time long ago when someone found a rogue server running on a non-80 port, and decided the best way to prevent this was to block all HTTP servers that are not on port 80.  In other words: an inappropriate over-generalization.

Perhaps I simply am not aware of it, but is there some valid rationale for restricting users to only access web servers on port 80?

Comment: Net admins have some strange ideas about security. Client-side port restrictions are another example. There is zero security benefit to it, and software that complies with it is essentially unimplementable, yet we keep reading about it here.

Comment: Running a service listening on port 1024 or lower requires root/Admin privileges on many, if not most, systems. And as such those services are more secure. There is also many systems that filter specific HTTP traffic, to run these filters on all traffic on all ports would be to CPU intensive and would affect other traffic, and as such many filter all other ports etc. The reasons for these kind of blocks are many.

Answer (score 1):

In the past there was an elevated risk of phishing/pharming attacks using high-port web servers, though these days it really isn't an issue.  The reason being was that in order to bind a listening socket to a lower order port on a *nix machine, you had to be root.  Attackers without root could phish or otherwise somehow direct users to point their browser at the evil listening socket and receive a payload.  These days the scenario described rarely if ever occurs.

It is also possible that an admin in the past sought to impede a user connecting to a proxy.  Proxies commonly listen on port 8080 for web requests.  If your organization has a policy that can be complied with by having this rule, then that may be the reason for its existence.

I personally see that rule as an annoyance rather than an effective filter.  Nowadays there are much better tools that do smart filtering so you don't have to rely on security through obscurity tricks like restricting HTTP to port 80.